# .animate jQuery towards bottom of image instead of top

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, effects

I am trying to do the opposite of the function

```
document.getElementById('testImage').style.height='75px';

$("#testImage").animate({
  height:'0px',
  width:'100px'
});
```

It has the perfect effect for my image but I want the animation to shrink a visible towards the bottom of the image instead of the top. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use an absolute position with `bottom: 0px`.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response! I ended up finding another solution that works for the moment but if I have any issue I will try all of these.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working in a fiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ku6vV/

```
$("#testImage").animate({
  height:'0px',
  width:'100px',
    top:'300px'
});
```

The CSS:

```
#testImage {
    position:relative;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: I built the function below to animate an image downwards exactly opposite of when you shorten the height. Set height to 0 and "top" to "+=" and the height of the image.

$("#testImage").animate({
      height:'0px',
      "top": "+=75px"
    });

Answer (score 0):

You just need to find some way to fix the image to the bottom of the area in question. For instance this could be achieved by setting the container to `position: relative`, the animated element to `position: absolute`, and `bottom: 0`.

Answer (score 0):

With CSS, set these rules for your image:

```
position:relative;
bottom:0px;
```

Make sure it's container has the proper height.